# USing split and adding link based on it

Tags: php

A webpage displaying a tabular info:
In thatt table one colunm  name WEB_DETAILS has

For example:

```
db1:app1:filename
db2:app2:filename
db3:app3:filename
db4:app4:filename
```

It goes on....

Now i want to add a hyperlink for each(1 to end)...The condition here is I want to create a hyperlink which show file based on app1,app2,app4....(imagine that these are folder names)..
WEB_DETAILS:The info in this comes from a query which retrives:
In that i want to split and extract based on: the app name..How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just do it like this:

```
 <a href="app1/filename"> db1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a loop that will output these HTML links. For example

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){ 
  echo "<a href='app$i/filename'>db$i</a><br>";
   }
 ?>
```

Although I don't know how that will fit into the context of your already existing table.